# mapkit layer modification on iphone 4

Tags: ios, iphone, mapkit

is there any way to load own map on mapkit using some layer modification and instead of Google I show my own map with compass effect on rotation?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom layers to a `MKMapView` easily with `MKOverlay` and related classes.  You could use a polygon, an image, or dynamically draw on demand.

You define a region using the `MKOverlay` protocol, and use a `MKOverlayView` to perform the actual rendering.

- [`MKOverlay` Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKOverlay)
- [`MKOverlayView` Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayView)

This is described in some detail in the developer documentation on Location Awareness, in the section [Drawing Overlays on a Map](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html).